# QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:Using criteria builder to make a difference between dates in postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to make the following query using Jpa Specification, I'm using Postgresql:

```
select * from record rec inner join record_history rec_hist on rec.id=rec_hist.official_record_id and (rec_hist.state=rec.state) where
extract(epoch from (current_timestamp - rec_hist.create_date)) > rec_hist.standard_duration
```

In the “toprediacte” method I have written the following code using criteria builder

```
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    Join historyJoin = root.join("recordHistory");
    historyJoin.on(cb.equal(historyJoin.get("state"), root.get("state")));

    Expression<Timestamp> epoch = cb.function(
            "epoch",
            Timestamp.class,
            new UnitExpression(null, String.class, "from"),
            historyJoin.<Timestamp>get("createDate"));

    Expression<Integer> extract = cb.function(
            "extract",
            Integer.class,
            epoch);

    Predicate durationPredicate = cb.greaterThan(historyJoin.<Integer>get("standardDuration"), extract);

    return cb.and(cb.and(super.toPredicate(root, cq, cb)), durationPredicate);
}
```

If I run this code I receive the following exception

```
 QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: , near line 1, column 323 [select generatedAlias0 from Record as generatedAlias0 inner join generatedAlias0.recordHistory as generatedAlias1 with generatedAlias1.state=generatedAlias0.state where ( 1=1 ) and ( generatedAlias1.standardDuration>function('extract', function('epoch', from, generatedAlias1.createDate)) )]]
```

Can you help me figure out how to implement this query?

Thanks

Comment: It's complaining because you use from in the function. For Hibernate this is a reserved word. I'm afraid but this may not work with criteria api

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found a work around using "interval '1 second'", but I don't know how to use it with criteria api. Do you now any way to use it?

Comment: Stupid question: Why don't you simply use your SQL select?

Comment: Because I think this is a simpler way. I need to add more dynamic conditions and pagination

Comment: I see. Do you know https://www.jooq.org? This would be a much better approach for your needs